# Is there an advantange/disadvantage to creating multiple FormViews in a single .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web-applications

I am developing an asp.net web application in c# for asset management.  Currently, I'm working on the functionality to insert records to 18 different tables.  Example: Adding a new Manufacturer to the Manufacturer table, or adding a new building to the building table.

I'm thinking of two options, having 18 different FormViews in one page, each with insert/edit templates, or having 18 different pages, a page with a form for each table.

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to having that many FormViews in one page?

Thank You!

Comment: While developing any system you first have to think about it's performance, reliability, and maintainability. So think about it. and you'll get answer that maintaining 18 formviews and there functionality on single page would be a tough task. But still you want to place all formviews in a single page then I suggest you to use TabContainer inside that you should manage your formviews. So it will look like userfriendly at least from user point of view.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The maintainability and performance were my concerns, that much code in one page does seem like it would be more difficult to maintain, the performance was one thing I wasn't sure about.  Would having that many Views bog the page down?  I am not familiar with a TabContainer, so I will look into that suggestion.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the feedback I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, That's an obvious thing. if you're handling 18 formviews on one single page which will be maintained by server then it will obviously decrease your performance. as each will have to intialize at some time. Performance will be decreased for sure. So I'll suggest you to do the work in smart way by creating 18 separate pages.

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about the performance of the page because if you put 18 page controls in one single page using FormViews it is not a recommended way to do.